# Error "The QName value X has no corresponding namespace declaration in scope" in BASE OAI-PMH Validator

Tags: xml, oai, oai-pmh

I want to validate OAI for a site using : http://oval.base-search.net/

But it gives me this error:

> ERROR: ListRecords response well-formed but invalid: Element '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}identifier', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value 'dcterms:DOI' has no corresponding namespace declaration in scope., line 38

I don't know meaning of it.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful the output of your OAI-PMH base URL with query

```
?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=oai_dc
```

Might be [something like](https://forum.pkp.sfu.ca/t/error-in-validation-at-base-oai-pmh-validator/38028):

```
<dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:DOI">10.123456/foo.bar.12122</dc:identifier>
```

Your XML is syntactically correct but not valid against the XML schema. AFAIK DOI is [not a default valid dcterm](http://dublincore.org/2012/06/14/dcterms) on unqualified DC. It could be on **[Qualified Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/dc-xml-guidelines/)**.

> Recommendation 7. Encoding schemes should be implemented using the 'xsi:type' attribute of the XML element for the property. The name of the encoding scheme should be given as the attribute value, and should be in the form of an XML qualified name (QName) which associates the scheme name with the appropriate namespace name. For example:
>
> ```
> <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://www.ukoln.ac.uk/</dc:identifier>
> ```

And

> [Note 2] Recommendation 7 specifies the use of 'xsi:type' to implement encoding schemes in Qualified Dublin Core. This allows implementors to take some advantage of the data typing functionality provided by the W3C XML Schema specifications [XMLSCHEMA].
>
> Some implementors have suggested instead the use of conventions which are independent of a specific schema definition language. One such convention is the use of a 'scheme' attribute of the XML element for the property. For example:
>
> ```
> <dc:identifier scheme="dcterms:URI">http://www.ukoln.ac.uk/</dc:identifier>
> ```
>
> This approach is not recommended by these guidelines. However, it may be sensible for software applications that consume DCQ in XML to accept this alternative representation, assuming it is correctly and consistently applied.